# Crear una nueva columna en tabla SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un problema y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme..

Tengo una tabla SQL con estas columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es crear una columna "Total" que sea precioUnidad*cantidad, pero he probado varios alter tables y no me han funcionado.

Probe con esta consulta : Alter Table factura1
Add Campo3 As (precioUnidad * cantidad);

Pero me tira este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es así `Alter Table factura1 Add Total decimal(18,2)` y luego ejecuta esto `update factura1 set Total = precioUnidad * cantidad`

Comment: pero lo que yo quiero es que cada vez que agrego un precioUnidad y una Cantidad el total se calcule automaticamente, sin tener que realizar updates.. es posible?

Comment: No se que no te funciona probé y me [funciono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958801/total-sum-of-two-columns-and-show-in-the-third-column) perfecto. `alter table [dbo].[Test] add [c]  AS ([a]+[b])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero agrega una nueva columna de tipo `INT` por que al menos con los datos que pones todos los resultados serán enteros, también con `AFTER` le indicas después de que columna la agregará:

```
ALTER TABLE precios add column totalFinal INT AFTER cantidad;
```

Posterior si haces un `select` obtendrás de tu tabla esto

```
select * from precios;
+--------------+----------+------------+
| precioUnidad | cantidad | totalFinal |
+--------------+----------+------------+
|            5 |       10 |       NULL |
|           14 |       10 |       NULL |
|           20 |       10 |       NULL |
|           30 |       10 |       NULL |
|           25 |       20 |       NULL |
+--------------+----------+------------+
```

Como notas la columna nueva tiene un valor de `NULL` por lo cual ahora le debemos asignar uno nuevo con una actualización de este modo:

```
UPDATE precios SET totalFinal = (precioUnidad * cantidad);
```

Ahora si haces un `select` de nuevo obtendrás

```
select * from precios;
+--------------+----------+------------+
| precioUnidad | cantidad | totalFinal |
+--------------+----------+------------+
|            5 |       10 |         50 |
|           14 |       10 |        140 |
|           20 |       10 |        200 |
|           30 |       10 |        300 |
|           25 |       20 |        500 |
+--------------+----------+------------+
```

Recuerda que como al `update` no le puse una condición de `WHERE` entonces hará la multiplicación en todas las filas

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Debes considerar que, para almacenar los datos de tu multiplicación; uses:

- `INT` si estas completamente seguro de que todos los resultantes serán números enteros, es decir carentes de valor decimal
- `DECIMAL` si van a salir números con puntuación decimal

**USO DEL TIPO DE DATO DECIMAL**

Si vas a almacenar un valor de este tipo *127.56* entonces la declaración de tu columna debería ser:

```
DECIMAL(5, 2);
```

Donde:

> - 5 es el número total de espacios asignados
> - 2 es el número asignado para almacenar los valores decimales
> - 3 serán los espacios dedicados para los números a la izquierda del punto decimal

**ACTUALIZACIÓN NO. 2**

```
MariaDB [demo]> CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW precioFinal AS SELECT *, (precioUnidad * cantidad) AS totalFinal FROM precios;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.054 sec)

MariaDB [demo]> SELECT * FROM precioFinal;
+--------------+----------+------------+
| precioUnidad | cantidad | totalFinal |
+--------------+----------+------------+
|            5 |       10 |       50   |
|           14 |       10 |       140  |
|           20 |       10 |       200  |
|           30 |       10 |       300  |
|           25 |       20 |       500  |
+--------------+----------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

> Haciendo caso a una recomendación de @Xeriff te comento que mejor
>   obtengas el resultado desde una `VIEW` que es un resultado temporal y
>   que no afecta la estructura original de la tabla en cuestión, la
>   sintáxis de arriba ayuda a obtener el valor deseado pero sobre una
>   columna que no se va a añadir a la tabla `precios` sino que se crea
>   sobre una vista

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho

Comment: @DavidBucci de nada recuerda marcarla como aceptada saludos

Comment: en donde? marque la flecha para arriba pero no hace nada.

Comment: @DavidBucci trata en la palomita gris del lado izquierdo

Comment: listo, gracias!

Comment: Añadiría como nota, que un campo como este que es calculado, no se debería almacenar en la base de datos, y que esto rompe 1FN y la atomicidad de los datos. Lo recomendable sería calcularlo en el `SELECT` o si es sumamente importante mostrar este dato en bd, crear una vista con el dato calculado. Ejemplo `SELECT precioUnidad, cantidad, (precioUnidad * cantidad) total FROM tabla;`

Comment: @Xerif gracias por la observación, lo había pasado por alto; pero ya lo agregué como ejemplo

Comment: @shadow Con tu permiso, edité la ultima parte de forma que quede el mismo resultado que en la primera parte de la respuesta. Si consideras oportuno revertirlo hazlo. Gracias.

Comment: al contrario @Xerif agradezco tanto la observación como la edición saludos